# How to Get More Entries on a Page?

Tags: channel-entries

If you look at this page on my website http://www.cambridgeusa.org/insider only 20 of my entries appear but I have many more. Is there a way to get all entries to appear?

Comment: What does your code for that list look like?

Answer (score 2):

set a high limit number to check, expression engine default channel limit is 100.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="100"}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set a limit in your channel:entries tag?